# 90s horror film about teens trapped in a haunted house

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

New to this forum, I've been trying to find a movie I watched as a kid. Hopefully I give you enough info that you guys can help me identify this movie:

1. This horror movie is from late 90s to early 00s.
2. About teens (or college students) that go into this haunted house. I believe it's in a suburban area.
3. They go into this house and each obstacle/trial/tribulation kills them. I think it was directed towards a significant person. Or the entity knew their weaknesses and used it against them
4. Second last scene (one that SCARRED me for life...can't look at mirrors at night), they are sitting in front of a mirror, one girl gets freaked out because either her reflection turns evil and kills the girl or some evil entity kills the reflection thus killing the girl.
5. Ending, a boy and a girl escape beaten and battered. It's a sunny morning. The movie pans to this elderly couple mowing the lawn, their necks suddenly have holes and starts spraying blood everywhere (I think at the 2 survivors).
6. English language, made in the US. The cast was your average jock, level headed girl, blonde bimbo, and African-American guy

Sorry, there's a lot of "I thinks" because it's been SOOOO long... I'd be really grateful if you can help me!

(It's not *House on Haunted Hill* or *House of Fears*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty much the plot of cult horror film [Night of the Demons](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093624/combined) from 1988.

> Ten teens decide to have a party at an abandoned funeral parlor called Hull House. Hull House is on a strip of land rumored to be unclean and unfit for human inhabitance. The house has a nasty history to it including a the Hull family being murdered. After the ten kids enter the house they decide to have a séance. After an attempt for the séance they awaken a demon that lives in the basement. It possesses one of the girls then from her everyone else becomes possessed and killed by demons that inhabit the land.

IIRC there are plenty of mirror scenes there, but in one of them, one of the girls sees a monster in it and then her own severed head. And in the end, the battered two survivors (a boy and a girl) walk by an old man's lawn, and he goes back inside, eats pie and gorily dies from swallowing razor blades (long story) while his wife looks on. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Just finished skimming through the movie...I think you nailed it! Thanks for lettin

Comment: Just finished skimming through the movie...I think you nailed! Thanks! My soul can finally rest in peace! I'm gonna save this for halloween!